# cast 'char *' to 'signed char *'

Tags: c, type-conversion

Is there any danger in casting a `char *` type to `signed char *` in C, where the char array is interpreted as a byte array.

I've read that in gcc, the `char` type can be either unsigned or signed depending on the system.  In the 'worst' case, the `char *` would be a `unsigned char *`, but as the array is just interpreted as a series of bits, it doesn't matter if the type goes from unsigned to signed.

(BTW, I've checked other posting, but I've only seen the question re: casting `unsigned char` to `signed char`, and I wondering if there's anything unique to just plain `char`.  Thanks in advance.)

Comment: I think it isn't an issue if you're using it as a binary data, however it _is_ if you're interpreting it as a numerical value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem in the cast itself, especially if you are just interpreting the array as bytes. In this case though I would suggest that you consider using the C99 types `uint8_t` and `int8_t` to convey your intentions better, if they are available to you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use the right type to explicitly show the intention behind it.

Comment: But `int8_t` may not be available. `signed char` is quite appropriate for the intention of "signed char"...

Comment: I did say "If they are available to you". Obviously this is something that depends on your environment. An alternative when they are not available would be to use a preprocessor define or `typedef` to clarify the representation you want to use for raw data bytes.

Comment: yeah I know some people have to write code that is C89 compliant, but it is usually for a library, and libraries that deal with things like that typically have their own types... APR, OpenGL, and SQLite come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

There's no danger, it's expressly allowed to reinterpret `char` pointers among all three char types, and also to reinterpret *any* object pointer as a char pointer (thus treating any object as an array of bytes).

Comment: There's no danger in the cast itself, but there may be if some later code depends on sign extension behaviour of one kind or another.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Sure, but I assume the OP has a reason why she wants a signed char and thus knows that...

Comment: Yeah, sure.  I just wanted to put it out there.

Answer (score 1):

there are some edge cases with comparisons after the assignment, but for storage and handing to different functions, no there isn't any danger...

also in your implementation char may be signed or unsigned by default...

example of a problem with comparison and signedness:

on MacOS X with clang in c99

```
char * dog = malloc(1);
dog[0]= 0xff;
unsigned char * mansBestFriend = dog;

if (mansBestFriend[0] > dog[0]) {
    puts("boy that is strange");
}
```

outputs: boy that is strange

because of the sometimes confusing comparison rules in C, the comparison happens in a way that may seem strange.

There are a lot of other times when this can happen, and the ones that I can never remember are the cases where one of the values is larger than the other and one is signed and the other is not... it is better to cast to be explicit if you are doing comparisons of disparate types.

Comment: `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)`, and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are all `1`.

Comment: Your 'strange' behaviour doesn't have anything to do with the ABI, either - just standard C type promotion rules.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right... though it can be affected by the ABI as a long and an int can be the same size, or a different size, and therefor follow different rules.

Comment: But that's still part of the C implementation, not the ABI.

Comment: No, it's up to the C implementation.  I'll grant that there are often some interrelationships.

Comment: I will concede to your superior knowledge of the subject, but I will point out that the x86 System V ABI specifies an equivalence between char and the signed byte type... But I haven't been able to find the final version for a very long time (since http://x86-64.org is dead), I can only find a Draft numbered "AMD ABI Draft 0.96"

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no danger in doing so since you only want to use it for its byte value.